Normalization of the Smooth Overlap of Atomic Positions (SOAP) Kernel
I am using the DScribe implementation (https://singroup.github.io/dscribe/latest/tutorials/descriptors/soap.html) of the Smooth overlap of atomic positions (SOAP) descriptor to generate it for my dataset and use it as an input for GPR(sklearn.gaussian_process with an exponentiated dot product kernel). I have managed to use this combination to make predicitions for molecular properties like intended, but ran into a problem: The cross-validated prediction errors are very low and the learning curves indicate a good fit, so the machine learning model seems to work.
But: I noticed that the SOAP-vectors obtained with the DScribe implementation are not normalized (as far as I understand) and in the original definition of the SOAP kernel (Phys. Rev. B 87, 184115-10 (2013)) it is stated that the SOAP kernel is defined as an (exponentiated) normalized dot product kernel. Now this raises the question to me, if it is always strictly necessary to normalize the SOAP vectors before using them as input for kernel methods:
$k(\rho, \rho') = \dfrac{\rho \rho'}{|\rho||\rho'|}$
If the answer is yes, I can not get my head around the fact that the results (obtained using a dot product or linear kernel with appropriate regularization) are so accurate. The fact that using the linear kernel gives way better results than polynomial kernels of degree >= 2 is also confusing for me because in the literature it is often stated that higher degrees lead to a higher ''sensitivity'' of the descriptor to changes in the molecular environment, which is associated with better performance.
I would appreciate it if anyone with some experience in using this descriptor would be able to help me resolve this problem.
NOTE:
I have tried normalizing the output of the Dscribe SOAP-implementation by using sklearn.preprocessing.normalize, and it gives totally different and slightly worse prediction errors with the settings of the kernel regressor I have originally used. What am I missing here ?

The rotational-invariant output from SOAP, partial power spectra ($p$), in Dscribe is built based on an un-normalized Gaussian smeared atomic density function. But, the SOAP kernel between two $p$ is already normalized.

Thank you for your comment. If I use the SOAP output from Dscribe without any rescaling or normalization as input for kernel methods (e. g. regression with the dot product kernel from sklearn), would this be equivalent to using a normalized kernel ? I am not sure if the kernels implemented in sklearn correspond to normalized kernels in that sense.
